# How to work with Enter Button and onclick in Javascript HTML form

Tags: javascript, dom

I am coding a simple calculator in JS & HTML. I am using **onclick** event for input type button. Everything is fine but this form only processes data if I click on the button , but doesn't work if I press ENTER key from keyboard.

Here is my HTML code

```
 <form> <input type="text" id="number1"/> 
<select id="operator"> 
<option value="+">+</option> 
<option value="-">-</option>
 <option value="*">*</option> 
<option value="/">/</option> 
</select> 
<input type="text" id="number2"/> 
<input type="button" onclick="getData('data.php','divTarget')" value="Calculate"/> 
</form>
```

**Note:** I may have multiple forms on this page so I cant use `event.keyCode == 13` **onkeydown** event. Because it may process any of the form if I press ENTER key. And No Jquery needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `onsubmit` handler in the form. You are just checking the button click, which isn't happening when you press enter.

So change your form tag:

```
<form onsubmit="getData('data.php','divTarget'); return false;">
```

And button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Calculate"/>
```

Comment: Update your code in the page, i don't see any difference to your original code.

Comment: Okay, you must add `return false;` to prevent form submitting. See my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

This should submit the form if you are typing in the input field and then press:

```
var inputField = document.getElementById("number2");
inputField.onkeyup(function(e) { 
        if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
            document.getElementsByTagName('form').submit();
        }
    } 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Then just code it in!

```
<input type = "text"
       id = "txtSearch" 
       onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13)
                        document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()"    
/>

<input type = "button"
       id = "btnSearch"
       value = "Search"
       onclick = "doSomething();"
/>
```